# Drupal 7 menus collapse for Views links

Tags: views, routes

When I reference a view name and/or view name with contextual filters in the menu Path for child menu items, they do not stay expanded on display of the view page.

I had this solved on another site, but for the life of me, I can't remember how I did it.

I don't want the expanded flag set force it always open. The only menu module I have loaded is Menu Attributes.